# Converting an InT field to date time

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, select, case

Im using MSSQL 2008 and have a field called AbsoluteDates that contains data in numeric for mat, for example

```
AbsoluteDates
20051216
20051217
20051218
10000
90
600
```

What i need to do is a "Select" statement that will ignore any date thats not 8 numbers in lenth and then convert the results to a datetime ,aso it should be like a case statement becuase i need to produce something when the length is not 8 charectors , for example the word " NotValid"

so for example , Select AbosluteDates from Calendar where lenth = 9 would give me the following results if i had the same data as above.

```
AbsoluteDates
2005-12-16 00:00:00.000
2005-12-17 00:00:00.000
2005-12-18 00:00:00.000
NotValid
NotValid
NotValid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast to varchar then a datetime like this and then back to a varchar:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(DateNumber) = 8 AND ISDATE(RTRIM(DateNumber)) = 1
    THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(25), 
        CAST(CAST(DateNumber as varchar(10)) as datetime), 121)
    ELSE 'NotValid' 
    END AS Result
FROM (
    SELECT 20051216 AS DateNumber
    UNION SELECT 20051217
    UNION SELECT 20051218
    UNION SELECT 10000
    UNION SELECT 90
    UNION SELECT 600
    UNION SELECT 99421946
) MySubQuery
ORDER BY Result
```

Just replace the hard-coded search with your actual data table

Comment: You might want to add `ISDATE(RTRIM(DateNumber)) = 1` to the `CASE` as well, since `99421946` will pass your test.

Comment: You could simplify it with using `AND` in the first `CASE` instead of adding an additional `CASE` tree, since the `ELSE` leads to the same result.

Comment: For some reason I had it in my head that you couldn't have multiple statements in a CASE statement; duly updated.